# Change image after number of clicks using javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, counter, countdown

I have a counter set to 100, i want that by clicking on default.jpg image the countdown begin to count the mouse clicks maded.
Now it works only by clicking on the href not over the image.
I also want that when the counter reach 50/25 click the image change with another one.
To understand better i need to make a simple breck the egg "tamago" game, i have no js skills.

Here is what i've done:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 100;
function linkClick(){
    document.getElementById('clicked').value = --clicks;
}

document.write('<a href="#" onclick="linkClick()">Click Me!</a>');
</script>


<script type ="text/javascript">
function changeimage()
{
if (clicks==100)
{
document.getElementById('myimage').src="defaul.jpg";
}
if (clicks==50)
{
document.getElementById('myimage').src="crack1.jpg";
}
if (clicks==25)
{
document.getElementById('myimage').src="crack2.jpg";
}

</script>
<img src="1.jpg" id="myimage" alt="" onmousedown="changeimage()">
clicks:<input id="clicked" size="3" onfocus="this.blur();" value="10" > times.
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Your `changeimage` function doesn't actually decrement the count anywhere..

Comment: Call `linkClick()` at the beginning of `changeimage()`.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a nice way of doing it. It's easy to read, and hopefully makes sense.

```
var count = 100;
var image = document.getElementById('myimage');
var images = ['default.jpg', 'crack1.jpg', 'crack2.jpg'];
image.src = images[0];

image.onclick = function(e)
{
    if(count > 50)
        image.src = images[0];
    else if (count > 25)
        image.src = images[1];
    else if (count > 0)
        image.src = images[2];
    else
    {
        //do something here to indicate the end
    }

    count--;
};
```

Comment: I suppose - I was just going for minimum code.. meh. I'll edit it and make it clearer.